# Call macro from combobox selection

Tags: excel, vba

I have added an activex combobox "ComboBox1" to my excel spreadsheet "Sheet1" and I want to be able to call different macros based on the selection in the combobox. Some of the macro names I have are "MC323", "MC616", "MC813".

So basically you select MC616 from the combobox list I want it to run the MC616 macro.

I have tried searching for answers but nothing has made since to me. Here is what I have so far, which isn't much and I'm sure isn't right anyway.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
With Sheet1.ComboBox1
ComboBox1.Clear
    .AddItem "MC323"
    .AddItem "MC616"
    .AddItem "MC813"
End With
End Sub

Sub ComoBox1_Change()
With Sheet1.ComboBox1
    Select Case ComboBox1.Value
        Case "MC323": MC323
        Case "MC616": MC616
        Case "MC813": MC813
    End Select
End With
End Sub

Sub MC323()
    Call MC323
End Sub

Sub MC616()
    Call MC616
End Sub

Sub MC813()
    Call MC813
End Sub
```

Comment: You haven't actually indicated what _isn't_ working, but I think [JNevill](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29701964/2344413) has hit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a spelling error, that could be an issue, anyway...
This should go into the Sheet1 module

```
Sub ComboBox1_Click()
    Select Case ComboBox1.Value
    Case Is = "MC323": MC323
    Case Is = "MC616": MC616
    Case Is = "MC813": MC813
    End Select
End Sub
```

This should go into a regular module,

```
Sub MC323()
    MsgBox "MC323"
End Sub

Sub MC616()
    MsgBox "MC616"
End Sub

Sub MC813()
    MsgBox "MC813"
End Sub
```

This is in the Workbook Module,

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    With Sheet1.ComboBox1
        .Clear
        .AddItem "MC323"
        .AddItem "MC616"
        .AddItem "MC813"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What if I wanted to put a "ENTER" button beside the combobox to let you select the item and then click the button to launch the macro?

Comment: Then the code would go in `Sub Button1_Click()` instead of `Sub ComboBox1_click()`.

Answer (score 1):

It all looks good until you get here:

```
Sub MC323()
    Call MC323
End Sub

Sub MC616()
    Call MC616
End Sub

Sub MC813()
    Call MC813
End Sub
```

Subroutine `MC323` has only one line and that line says to call subroutine `MC323` which has only one line and that line and that line says to call subroutine `MC323` which has only one line and that line says to call subroutine `MC323` which has only one line and that line says to call subroutine `MC323` which has only one line and that line says to call subroutine `MC323` which has only one line and that line says to call subroutine `MC323` which has only one line and that line asays to call subroutine `MC323`.

So anyway, you get into a endless recursive loop, which is no good. Don't call subroutine `MC323` inside of `MC323`. Put the code you want ran into the subroutine `MC323`. Like...

```
Sub MC323()
    MsgBox("Endless recursive loops are bad")
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm actually trying to get it to call a VBA module named MC323. How would I go about that?

Comment: In that case... You have probably have a subroutine names MC323 inside of a Modules named.. "Module1" or something like that. You can call it inside of `MC323()` with the line `Call Modules1.MC323()`.  Your probably best off renaming the subroutines inside your sheet, or inside your Module so that you don't accidently call the wrong `MC323()`

Comment: If you put a breakpoint (press `F9`) on this line: `Select Case ComboBox1.Value`, then debug through your code (press `F8`), I think you'll find that @JNevill has correctly identified your problem. Your code is calling the appropriate `Sub`, but that `Sub` doesn't actually do any useful work.

Answer (score 0):

I've been wondering why I couldn't get my examples to work - **MC323, MC616 and MC813 are also worksheet cell references.**

So..... ensure you have a sheet with a codename Sheet1 and an ActiveX combo-box called ComboBox1.
In the ThisWorkbook module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    With Sheet1
        .ComboBox1.Clear
        .ComboBox1.AddItem "MC323"
        .ComboBox1.AddItem "MyMacro2"
        .ComboBox1.AddItem "MyMacro3"
    End With

End Sub
```

Note the first item will cause an error - **'Cannot run the macro 'MC323'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.**

In a normal module:

```
Public Sub MC323()
    MsgBox "1"
End Sub

Public Sub MyMacro2()
    MsgBox "2"
End Sub

Public Sub MyMacro3()
    MsgBox "3"
End Sub
```

Finally, in the Worksheet module for Sheet1:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Application.Run Sheet1.ComboBox1.Value
End Sub
```

**Useful links to help files:**

[Application.Run Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197132.aspx)

[Ron de Bruin - How do I use Application.Run in Excel](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win001.htm)